# JIRA SOAP API: "Email This Issue" possible via SOAP call?

Tags: api, email, soap, jira

Is it possible to call the "Email This Issue" method (url shows "com.metainf.jira.plugin.emailissue.action.EmailThisIssue") from SOAP?  I would like to email this issue to the assignee with a custom description.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to do this through the API - http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html

One alternative is to use the SOAP API to comment or, or otherwise update the issue, which should generate an email (depending on your notification scheme).

Depending on your use case you might also be able use subscriptions to meet your goal http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Receiving+Search+Results+via+Email

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to use a JIRA URL directly without SOAP at http://jiradev.blogspot.com/2011/08/adding-components-to-jira-automatically.html
This may be the easiest way to do what you want.

~Matt